# Perl, Inserting a 2D hash into mySQL db

Tags: mysql, perl, hash, hashtable

I have a 2D hash which I have to insert in a mySQL db .. Now the names of the columns in mysql table (report) are the same as

```
  'vm_uuid'  
  'ip_addr'  
  'name'
  'config_name'
  'PrimaryKey' 
  'ComputeNode'
```

Data dumper for the hash is:

```
p Dumper %Final
$VAR1 = 'ZTestName1',
$VAR2 = {          'vm_uuid' => '096a18bd-5955-465f-9bd4-d6bd038a4a56|',
          'ip_addr' => '107.250.172.198|172.26.3.8|',
          'name' => 'tap6f684e07-7a|tapa19310a9-7a|',
          'config_name' => 'TestValue',
          'PrimaryKey' => 'TestName',
          'ComputeNode' => 'TestName',
$VAR3 = 'DummyName1';
$VAR4 = {          'PrimaryKey' => '',
          'ComputeNode' => 'TestName',
          'ip_addr' => '|',
          'vm_uuid' => '|',
          'name' => 'bond0.2004|vhost0|pkt0|',
          'config_name' => '|'        };
$VAR5 = 'DummyName2';
$VAR6 = {          'name' => 'tap98655839-61|',
          'config_name' => 'TestValue',
          'ip_addr' => '107.250.162.244|',
          'vm_uuid' => '903904a7-6b05-489c-9945-ee69cbf5c94f|',
          'ComputeNode' => 'TestName',
          'PrimaryKey' => 'MULTI-SITE: TESTING FOR MULTI-SITE FOR 1607'        };
$VAR7 = 'ZTestName2',
$VAR8 = {          'ComputeNode' => 'TestName',
          'PrimaryKey' => 'ZTestName',
          'config_name' => 'TestValue',
          'name' => 'tap2000b14d-29|tap3ea0942c-66|tap479c2ab0-4e|tapc1c4f00b-de|',
          'ip_addr' => '107.239.45.6|107.250.169.168|107.243.36.9|107.239.44.9|',
          'vm_uuid' => 'ae7aa321-6e3a-4572-a783-ebfcf250ed98|'        };
```

The code I am trying is

```
my @keys = keys %Final; 
my @values=values %Final; #value to be inserted - this doesnt work, as its hash ref in my opinion
my $sth=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table`(@keys) VALUES (@values)");
```

This code will get the keynames, and values (which would be a hash ref in itself) .. what would the good way to insert the data of 2D hash presented above into a mysql table?

Comment: FYI, the output of Data::Dumper is much easier to read if you pass it a reference: `print Dumper \%hash;` instead of `print Dumper %hash;`

Answer (score -1):

try with something like:

```
foreach my $real_hashref_to_insert ( values %Final ){
    my @keys = keys %$real_hashref_to_insert;
    my @values = values %$real_hashref_to_insert;
    my $field_placeholders = join ", ", map {'?'} @keys;
    my $sth=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table`(".join ',' @keys.") VALUES ($field_placeholders)");
    $sth->execute(@{$real_hashref_to_insert}{@keys}); #hash slice
}
```

Which is heavily inspired from the [DBI recipes post on Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436#inshash).

Comment: `@keys` and `@values` seem to contain the same thing?

Comment: true - there are more errors - I try to correct as many as possible now

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm 99% certain @keys was supposed to be created using `keys`, not `values`.

Comment: you already have the values in `@values`.  Why are you bothering to go back to the hash to get them again for the `execute()` call?  While the ordering of a hash is (semi-)random, the order [is guaranteed to be consistent between `keys()` and `values()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html)

Comment: This solution doesn't save the original keys of `%Final`, which are presumably essential to the data. It's also very wasteful to repeatedly `prepare` the same SQL statement, and the SQL statement has no commas between the column names

Comment: @Borodin, while you were right regarding the lack of comma for `@keys` in the insert (which I corrected), try and come up with a solution to also insert the original keys of the %Final hash within the given specifications

Comment: Though there is no error .. but I also dont see any thing being added to my table... that is pretty weird .. am i missing something ?



    54:                 my $sth=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $tableName(" . join(', ',@keys) . ") VALUES ($field_placeholders)");
  DB<2> p "INSERT INTO $tableName(" . join(', ',@keys) . ") VALUES ($field_placeholders)"
INSERT INTO VMtoComputeReport(virtual_network, vrouter, gateway, ip_address, PrimaryKey) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

  DB<5> $test = $sth->execute(@{$real_hashref_to_insert}{@keys})

  DB<6> p $test
1